# Current mode operation of a source measurement unit (SMU)

Tags: current, measurement, source

I'm studying semiconductor parameter analyzers. In particular, I have difficulties in fully understanding the circuit in the following slide, which represents an SMU operating in I-mode (i.e., it injects a current in the device under test and measures the voltage on it):

[image]

I start assuming ideal "error amplifier" block, thus the concept of virtual ground applies; as a consequence all the current which flows in R1 must flow in R2 as well. In this way, I easily find the **output** voltage of the "differential amplifier" block of the picture.

**Question 1:** why is it written that this voltage is also the voltage on Rr? The voltage on Rr should be de-amplified by the gain of the "differential amplifier" block

**Question 2:** It can be a stupid question, but this circuit has created in me a doubt: what about if I apply virtual-ground concept for the 2 inputs of the "differential amplifier" block? Rr would be short-circuited and the circuit would have no meaning, then the question: why am I allowed to use virtual-ground concept for the "error amplifier" block and not for the "differential amplifier" block?

Thank you

Comment: Could you show what you mean by virtual ground? There is a circuit tool, draw the modified circuit.

Comment: The differential amplifier block is not an ideal opamp with infinite gain - it has internal feedback to give a defined gain and present an output that is relative to ground equal to some multiple of the voltage across the sense resistor Rr. The error amplifier however can be represented by an ideal I-amp with infinite gain for which your virtual ground concept applies.

Comment: Many errors on this diagram including schematic and formula including \$V_R=-\dfrac{R1}{R2}\cdot V_{ref}\$

Comment: Sorry to bother you, it would be very nice if you could send me the reference of the lecture relative to that slide (or the affiliations of the person) ? I'm highly interested to model an SMU in Imode within LTspice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might all become clear if you consider that the function of the differential amplifier is to measure the voltage across Rr and present the same voltage on the output of the differential amplifier with respect to ground.  Using your virtual ground technique, you correctly (and easily) found the output voltage of the differential amplifier.  Since this output voltage (with respect to ground) is the same as the voltage across Rr, the Error Amplifier output will be driven to whatever voltage is necessary to achieve this voltage across Rr. So you are sensing the voltage across sense resistor Rr and adjusting the output to give you a current source which is proportional to Vref.